# NoSql,Hbase,Cassandra Conceptualization db

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hbase

Suppose I have a relationship 1 to N, for example

```
Student , College.
```

Student Attributes:

```
Name,Surname,CollegeFKey,
```

College attributes:

```
CollegeKey,Other,Other.
```

Suppose that I have a program which read students and Exams from a plain text file. And, on this file I have duplicated Colleges and Duplicated Studends.

Like in denormalized tables:

```
CollegeId,Other,Other,Name,Surname,CollegeFkey.
```

e.g.

```
1,x,y,Mike,M,1
1,x,y,R,P,1
...
...
...
```

You see, I have to check in this case always that in my normalized db, I have still not inserted in the Table College 2 times the key 1.

How can I solve this in Hbase or Cassandra? I mean, if I have 10000.. tables and rows, I don't want check for every Primary Key and then for every FK, if it was inserted OK?

How can I solve that?  I can use no-sql db for work directly in de-normalized datas?
Can you link me to an example that solve this problem?

Comment: talking with some hbase users the answer can be found in the book "hadoop :the definitive guide", practically one should use Pig Latin for perform sql-likes queries or Hive non slq-like queries for this kind of problem. I hope this can help. On cassandra side i think i m still not expericend so much so i hope users comment on that. – user448381 2 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cassandra http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ with some high level language client (I use Hector for java https://github.com/rantav/hector). In Cassandra you will describe ColumnFamily College in this ColumnFamily you write Student columns which contains information about students.